# How to define and access to static properties as a top-level member in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, class, static, static-members, toplevel

I want to have a simple `static` member in a class with simple access i.e I like to have a `class_name.static_data` instead of `class_name.shared_obj.static_data`.

I've searched and find the [standard method of defining static members in `Matlab` classes, on mathwork.com as you can see below.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-data.html)

```matlab
classdef SharedData < handle  % an auxiliary class to keep static data
    properties
        Data1
        Data2
    end
end

classdef UseData  % main class
    properties (Constant)
        Data = SharedData
    end
    % Class code here
end
```

and then we can use it with something like this:

```matlab
k = UseData
k.Data.Data1=5; % Want to be `k.Data1=5;` instead.
```

BUT I'm looking to have a top-level `static` member

( something like

`obj_of_UseData.Data1=5;`

NOT

`obj_of_UseData.Data.Data1=5;` )

(i.e. like a top-level member, not second-level one). I seek a method to implement top-level `static` member , not second-level one.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just do `Data1 = SharedData.Data1` in the `UseData` class, then access it using `k.Data1`? Without doing this, it makes no logical sense to omit the `Data` property when accessing `Data1` from the other class...

Comment: @Wolfie No. If you use `Data1 = SharedData.Data1`,then `Data1` in main class loses its `handle` mood. It would be just a value that is specific to that object and loses its `static`-ness. We need a `static` member.

Comment: "Static" can mean something specific when talking about objects/classes. You talk about a "static member" and yet show a constant property in your example. What exactly you mean by "static" in this case? Static, as in [static method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html) or do you mean a constant property, or something else?

Comment: @Behzad You want the property to act like a handle but be constant? That doesn't align. Either you want it to change when it changes in the original parent class or you don't... Sounds like you want to implement it as a dependent property, which is accessed automatically through a getter function - pulling the value from the handle object. This is in no way static or constant though.

Comment: @Wolfie I just mentioned mathworks.com classic way to create a static member. Don't bother yourself with this code , I just need to have a simple top-level `static` member, with anyway possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to follow [the advice from the MathWorks related to static data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-data.html), and still create behavior that makes it look like those variables are members. You can do so by overloading the `subsref` and `subsasgn` methods like below. This codes uses the static method way of creating static data, since it is simplest, but the idea translates to the other method, using a handle class, as well.

```
classdef UseData
   properties
      Data3
   end
   methods (Static)
      function out = setgetVar(name,value)
         persistent data;
         if isempty(data)
            data = struct('Data1',[],'Data2',[]);
         end
         if nargin==2
            data.(name) = value;
         end
         out = data.(name);
      end
   end
   methods
      function obj = subsref(obj,S)
         if isequal(S(1).type,'.')
            if strcmp(S(1).subs,'Data1') || strcmp(S(1).subs,'Data2')
               obj = UseData.setgetVar(S(1).subs);
               return
            end
         end
         obj = builtin('subsref',obj,S);
      end
      function obj = subsasgn(obj,S,value)
         if isequal(S(1).type,'.')
            if strcmp(S(1).subs,'Data1') || strcmp(S(1).subs,'Data2')
               UseData.setgetVar(S(1).subs,value);
               return
            end
         end
         obj = builtin('subsasgn',obj,S,value);
      end
   end
end
```

To see it working:

```
>> x = UseData;
>> y = UseData;
>> x.Data1 = 'bla';
>> y.Data2 = [5,6];
>> x.Data3 = 0;
>> y.Data3 = 10;
>> y.Data1
ans = bla
>> x.Data2
ans =
   5   6
>> x.Data3
ans = 0
>> y.Data3
ans =  10
```

Comment: +1 Good, Very good, but it is too complicated , really , it uses parsing. Technique you used is beautiful but I'm seeking some straight-forward non-parsing method.

Comment: @Behzad the simpler method is to actually define what behaviour you want clearly and concisely in an [edit], then structure your code in a neat way. You're starting at "I want to use this unusual approach but have simple code as if it were the normal way to do X", when it's likely not the normal way.

Comment: @BehzadSeyfi: It's not really parsing, though. It is comparing the name after the dot to make sure it's one of the "special" names. Then all other indexing is processed in the built-in manner.

Comment: @Wolfie I made my all effort to make the question as much neat and fluent as possible,and edited two times, I'm sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think changing line 5 to `methods (Static,Access=private)` is far better, because static call won't change object instances shared static member. Then something like `UseData.setgetVar('Data1',8)` wont change static property shared among objects.

Comment: @Behzad: Yes, that would be better, I agree.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Checked as accepted answer as there is no other answer after two weeks. thanks